# looking for a laptop without a plastic shell

Tags: laptop

I am hoping to move away from the apple ecosystem soon, but one thing that I really like about the macbook pros is the aluminum shell. I would like to either buy a laptop without a case or one that I could I could easily remove the casing from, and then custom manufacture a aluminum shell for it.

Alternatively, is there another manufacturer who makes metal shelled laptops?

I have done some googling, but nothing useful came up, only talking about linux shells.

Comment: is there a better place to ask this type of question on stack exchange or should I take my question to reddit?

Answer (score 1):

Some examples I thought of:

The new Alienware laptops are made of anodized-aluminium shells, though the brand is expensive.

HP Pavilion has an aluminium shell too.

[This](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Laptops-Aluminium-Computers-Accessories/s?ie=UTF8&page=1&rh=n%3A429886031%2Cp_n_feature_keywords_browse-bin%3A1628942031) link to Amazon shows you quite a lot.

Otherwise you could just go and search for custom-made laptops-most let you choose the shell.